# record variable in postgresql needs to be dynamically passed

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am facing issue while taking value from a record variable to use as a table to insert.

```
DECLARE
   validation_table record;
   mirror_table record;
BEGIN
   FOR validation_table IN  
      select validationrule,businesscolumnname,businesstablename 
      from ipte_cds.error_validation_rule
      group by validationrule,businesscolumnname,schemaname
   LOOP
      For mirror_table in 
         select src_sys_id from validation_table.businesstablename
         where validation_table.businesscolumnname is null
      LOOP
         insert into ipte_cds.mac_error_event_log
            businesscolumnname,
            businesstablename,
            validationrule,
            src_sys_id
         select
            validation_table.businesscolumnname,
            validation_table.businesstablename,
            validation_table.validationrule,
            mirror_table.src_sys_id
         from validation_table, mirror_table;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: validation_table record; 
mirror_table record; 
FOR validation_table IN 
is the first lines of the code

Comment: This code has syntax errors. Moreover, you are using a cross join. But the worst thing is that there is no clear question.

Comment: Your question is? :-)

Comment: @pradeep, maybe using the EXECUTE or EXECUTE FORMAT might help. Take a look at this link https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html

Comment: thanks Ed, it was useful,